# Java BoneCP Sybase - "JZ0C0: Connection is already closed."

Tags: java, sybase, bonecp

I used BoneCP for a long time and now I must use it with a Sybase database.

The problem appears when I stop the Sybase service. 
While Sybase is stopped all connections in BoneCP give me the error "JZ0C0: Connection is already closed" and all connections that received this error are forever blocked in BoneCP because:

- `conn.close();` on these connections give me the same error and can't be released. Even if I restart Sybase, when I try to `conn.close();` the same error appears again.
- if I start Sybase service I will never receive a connection that was not released.

If I restart Sybase 3-4 times this problem will eat all Sybase available connections.

Thank you.

Comment: That sounds like a bug in BoneCP then (or a bug in the Sybase JDBC that BoneCP isn't handling well). Can you upgrade BoneCP and see if that fixes it, or try the replacement HikariCP that they recommend instead? If not you make have to debug into BoneCP yourself to work out what's going wrong.

Comment: I solved the problem temporary by restarting the pool. I will try HikariCP